# Vectors - collinear and perpendicular

Tags: vector-spaces, vector-analysis

A bird is at point $P$ whose coordinates are $(4, -1, 5)\text{m}$. The bird observes two points $P_1$ and $P_2$ having coordinates $(-1,2,0)$ and $(1,1,4)$ respectively. At time $t = 0$, it starts flying in the plane of three positions with a constant speed of $5 \text{m/s}$ in a direction perpendicular to the straight line $P_1P_2$ till it sees them collinear at time '$t$'. Calculate '$t$'.

For the conditions to be satisfied, the position of the bird at time '$t$' should be collinear to $P_1P_2$ and perpendicular to $P$. However, I don't know where to proceed from there. We are required to solve this question using properties of vectors.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distance_from_a_point_to_a_line

Comment: @lemon This is in three dimensions?

Comment: It is in the plane of the three points (4,-1,5),(-1,2,0) and (1,2,4)

Answer (score 1):

Here are some hints.

- Given three points $a,b,c$ in the plane, how can you calculate two vectors in the plane?
- Given two vectors in the plane, how can you calculate a vector normal $n$ to the plane?
- What conditions must be satisfied for the bird's flight direction $v$ to be both in the plane and perpendicular to the vector defined by the two points the bird is looking at?  (It must be perpendicular to two vectors.  Which ones?)
- Once the bird reaches the point of colinearity, what conditions are met?
- How is the distance from $P$ to this point calculated?  How is the time $t$ calculated from this distance?

Comment: For the first part, I believe I can calculate vector ab and then bc?

Comment: Yes. Do you know about the cross product of two vectors?

Comment: @almagest Of course.

Comment: Then you should be able to do the second part too, because you will know that the cross product vector is normal to the plane of the two vectors.

Comment: @almagest Well of course. So..... Wait I don't understand the first point then. How would I calculate two vectors in a plane?

Comment: You have the bird's position $B$ at (4,-1,5) and $P_1$ at (-1,2,0). Do you know how to get the vector BP?

Comment: @Gummybears take the componentwise difference. The vector that points from $a = (a_x, a_y, a_z)$ to $b = (b_x, b_y, b_z)$ is $(b_x - a_x, b_y - a_y, b_z - a_z)$.